# Container is not defined problem in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, rxjs

I'm trying to learn React but this 'Container' is not defined and I don't know why I got this error, even though I did everything in the course

Here is App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Row } from "reactstrap";
import CategroyList from "./CategroyList";
import Navi from "./Navi";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container> //'Container' is not defined
        <Row>
          <Navi />
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <CategroyList />
          <ProductList />
        </Row>
      </Container>



    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here json code and I downloaded last reacstrap version and I imported the 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in my index.js file but as you see I still take error

```
  "name": "intro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't imported `Container` into the component which is why it's undefined. `import { Container, Row } from "reactstrap";` perhaps? Also your `CategroyList` component should probably be spelled `CategoryList` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `Container` import on line 2:

```
import { Row, Container } from "reactstrap";
```